# Position included Pdf in twosided document using A4 papersize and C5 layout

Tags: geometry, pdfpages, double-sided, crop

I want to position included Pdf in twosided document, actual size C5 but printed on A4 paper, showing cropping marks. Included Pdf has already set `hmarginratio` to 2:3, so I need to center him correctly. The bellow example position correctly on right side.

```
\documentclass[ %draft
         % , demo  % black boxes instead of figures
          , 8pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{extbook}
\usepackage%[showframe]
       {geometry}

% Basic geometry of document
\geometry
{ headsep    =   \baselineskip
, textwidth  = 42\baselineskip
, textheight = 60\baselineskip
, hmarginratio =  2:3
, vmarginratio = 2:3
, bindingoffset = 0cm
, onecolumn
, layout=c5paper
, layoutoffset = {2cm,2cm}
, showcrop
}

 % Geometry of the cover pages
 \newcommand\covergeometry{\newgeometry
  { textwidth  = 42\baselineskip
  , textheight = 60\baselineskip
, hmarginratio = 1:1
, vmarginratio = 2:3
, bindingoffset = 0cm
, onecolumn
, layout=c5paper
, layoutoffset = {2cm,2cm}
, showcrop
}} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage
\covergeometry  
\makeatletter
\includepdf[
 pages={2,1,3,4},
 turn=false,
 width=\Gm@layoutwidth,
 height=\Gm@layoutheight,
 offset={\dimexpr(\Gm@layoutwidth-\paperwidth)/2+\Gm@layouthoffset\relax}
 {\dimexpr(\paperheight-\Gm@layoutheight)/2-\Gm@layoutvoffset\relax}
  ]{gram.pdf}
 \makeatother
 \restoregeometry  
 \clearpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centering the layout offset in geometry settings

```
, layouthoffset=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname)/2\relax
  , layoutvoffset = 2cm
```

together with adjusting the offset of included pdf helped to adjust the included pdf.

```
 offset={\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname)/2-\csname Gm@layouthoffset\endcsname\relax}
  {\dimexpr(\paperheight-\csname  Gm@layoutheight\endcsname)/2-\csname Gm@layoutvoffset\endcsname\relax}
```